# Setting reply_to properties in RabbitListener

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm a newbie in RabbitMQ. I use the following listener in my Spring configuration:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue.a}")
@SendTo("${rabbitmq.queue.b}")
public ResponseMessage receive(RequestMessage request) {
    ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();
    response.setRawPayload(jsonMapper.toJson(request));
    return response;
}
```

And I would like that when sending a message to the *rabbitmq.queue.b* queue from this method, the "reply_to "property should be set to this message.

```
@Value("${rabbitmq.queue.b}")
private String responseQueue;

@Bean
Queue responseQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder
            .durable(responseQueue)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is that "should be set to this message.", but `reply_to` can be handled with something like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue.a}")
@SendTo("${rabbitmq.queue.b}")
public Message<ResponseMessage> receive(RequestMessage request) {
    ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();
    response.setRawPayload(jsonMapper.toJson(request));
    return org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(response)
                 .setHeader(AmqpHeaders.REPLY_TO, "YOUR_QUEUE_NAME_FOR_REPLY")  
                 .build();
}
```